# How to submit a dynamic dropdown list with php in a table (tr,td)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question, apparently I was able to do a dropdown list where I was able to retrieve the values from MYSQL, however, now I want it to insert into a new query, below 2 codes contains how I place my dropdown list, and the other codes would be how I insert and submit the data. So my question is how do i submit the sbranch_name from the dropdown list to the next page in order for me to post it?

```
<form action="processstaffb.php" method="post">
    <table id="t01">
        <h2> Add Staff User </h2>
        <tr>
            <th width="1%">Branch</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="1%">
                <?php
                session_start();
                $mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
                $sql="Select sbranch_name from branches";
                $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<select name1='sbranch_name'>";
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                }
                $mysqli->close();
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="button2" name="submit" value="Add staff" />
    <input type="reset" id="button2" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

codes for i am sending through to the next page,

```
    if (!empty($_POST['sbranch_name'])) 
{
   $sbranch_name =$_POST["sbranch_name"];
}
else 
{ 
   $sbranch_name = null;
   echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the branch of the officer!</font></p>';
    // testing whether i have managed to bring over.
    echo "$name1";
    echo "$sbranch_name";

}

if ($sbranch_name)
{

$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO staffbranch 
(sbranch_name) 
VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sbranch_name);
$result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result == true && $stmt->affected_rows>0) {        

     echo "<b>". $check . "</b><br>";

 }
 else
 {
     echo '<p>Please <a href="addstaffb.php">Click Here</a> to return</p>'; 

 }
$stmt->fetch(); 
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();   
}
else 
{
echo '<p>Please <a href="addstaffb.php">Click Here</a> to return</p>';  
}
```

Comment: For the name of `select`, please use `name` attribute instead of `name1`, then you could post it in anyway you want, e.g. normal form post, ajax, ...

Comment: as Phil pointed out, `<select name1` <<< is a typo here. `name1` is not a valid attribute. Check for errors with error reporting for the php and `mysqli_error($mysqli)` on the query, what do those show?